# repeated addition and square root of fixed number

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, gm.general-mathematics, recurrences

pick any real number $x$ and integer $k$ and do the following recursive :

1) $x_0 =x $

2) $x_{n+1} = x_n + \sqrt x_n$

using only $x$ and $k$ how to find the value of $x_k$ without  going through recursive computation (meaning a formula) ?!

also i didn't know what tags to attach to this problem so i put just GM ^_^

Comment: Why do you think an explicit, closed-form formula can be given? What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Do you want asymtotics or an algorithm?

Comment: Mayeb you w'd like to connect this problem to number theory under this question :When is $x_n$ is perfect square , equivalent to :$({x_{n+1}-x_{n}})²=x_{n }$, in any way i don't think if your difference equation converges

Comment: Since your function $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x}$ satisfies f(x)>x for x>0, the sequence diverges for any positive starting value ...